# How to reduce font size text?

Tags: fontsize

Having this commands:

```
\paragraph
\begin{abstract}
```

how is it possible to reduce the font size text? I tried this but it is not the appropriate choice:

```
\paragraph{8}
\begin{abstract}{8}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The font size for an abstract is usually defined in a document class.  So changing it requires knowing what document class you are using.  Please provide a small compilable example that shows exactly how you are trying to use these commands.  Without that information, all we can provide are random guesses, which are usually no help at all.

Comment: The `\paragraph` command is completely out of place. It *doesn’t* start a paragraph as the name seems to imply, but is a sectional command below the subsubsection  level.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not recommended, but if you really need it, you can use one of the commands giving a smaller size. They are `\small`, `\footnotesize`, `\scriptsize`, and `\tiny`. So for example

```
\begin{abstract}
\footnotesize % it depends on the size used in abstract
The text
\end{abstract}
```

should be the (not recommended) solution.